# How do I assign a google sheet a owner and save location using pygsheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, pygsheets

I'm using pygsheets to work with google sheets and need to assign myself as the owner with my email and have it save to my google drive but I'm struggling to find a solution in the documentation.

The best I have is:

```
sheetbook=gs.create(gsheet_name)
sheetbook.share('my@email.com', role='writer')
```

I tried changing role to owner but come up with a error saying that transferOwnership needs a permission change and that's the issue of me not knowing how to do so. I know of the "folder=" option in create but I don't know how to link my google drive root folder.

Comment: sounds like something that the `owner` of the sheet would grant....

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `need to assign myself as the owner with my email and have it save to my google drive`. In your situation, who is the owner of the original Spreadsheet? And, do you have permission for changing the owner of the Spreadsheet?

Comment: The owner of the sheet is the email given by the service account credentials in my google projects, it's a iam.gserviceaccount.com email. The owner isn't a human that can swap ownership over.

Comment: FWIW, I found https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/pull/312